# Pandas Dataframe with start and end date, combine connected dates from multiple rows to one row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets assume I have the following df:

```
category    start   end
0   A   2015-01-01  2016-01-01
1   A   2016-01-01  2016-06-01
2   A   2016-06-01  2016-12-01
3   B   2016-01-01  2016-07-01
4   B   2018-01-01  2018-08-01
```

Now for each category, if the previous rows end date is equal to current rows start date, i'd like to "merge" them, and if not just keep them. Keeping the index is not important.
The output would be

```
category    start   end
0   A   2015-01-01  2016-12-01
3   B   2016-01-01  2016-07-01
4   B   2018-01-01  2018-08-01
```

```
a = {'category':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']}
b = {'start': [datetime(2015, 1,1).date(), datetime(2016, 1,1).date(), datetime(2016, 6, 1).date(), datetime(2016, 1,1).date(), datetime(2018, 1,1).date()]}
c = {'end':[datetime(2016, 1,1).date(), datetime(2016, 6,1).date(), datetime(2016, 12, 1).date(), datetime(2016, 7,1).date(), datetime(2018, 8,1).date()]}

a.update(b)
a.update(c)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a)
```

My original DataFrame has about 8 million rows. By doing this I could get that down to about 1 million. But it has to be able to perform on somewhat "large" data.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

1. `stack` all the dates into one column
2. `drop_duplicates`: effectively getting rid of equal end and start dates
3. Keep every second row and restructure the result

```
df = df.sort_values(["category", "start", "end"])
stacked = df.set_index("category").stack().droplevel(-1).rename("start")
output = stacked.reset_index().drop_duplicates(keep=False).set_index("category")
output["end"] = output["start"].shift(-1)
output = output.iloc[range(0, len(output.index), 2)]

>>> stacked
              start        end
category                      
A        2015-01-01 2016-12-01
B        2016-01-01 2016-07-01
B        2018-01-01 2018-08-01
```

Comment: Nice solution, correct me if I am wrong, but this would assume that there are no overlapping intervals correct? Because otherwise the drop_duplicate might screw up the "every second row" logic.

Comment: Indeed. But since OP mentioned "if the previous rows end date is **equal to** current rows start date", I thought it was safe to assuming non-overlapping intervals! :)

Comment: Yes, I think so too, but I think its worth pointing out.

Comment: Of course, and I'm glad you did so that I could explain !

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

**Sample data:**

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'category': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'B'}, 'start': {0: '2015-01-01',  1: '2016-01-01',  2: '2016-06-01',  3: '2016-01-01',  4: '2018-01-01'}, 'end': {0: '2016-01-01',  1: '2016-06-01',  2: '2016-12-01',  3: '2016-07-01',  4: '2018-08-01'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

**Code:**

```
# Create a series of boolean essentially marking the start of a new continuous group
df = df.sort_values(['category', 'start', 'end'])
mask_continue = ~df['start'].eq(df['end'].shift())
mask_group = ~df['category'].eq(df['category'].shift())
df['group'] = (mask_continue | mask_group).cumsum()

# group by that above generated group and get first and last value of it
g = df.groupby('group')
g_start = g.head(1).set_index('group')[['category', 'start']]
g_end = g.tail(1).set_index('group')['end']

# combine both
g_start['end'] = g_end
```

**Output:**

```
print(g_start)

      category       start         end
group
1            A  2015-01-01  2016-12-01
2            B  2016-01-01  2016-07-01
3            B  2018-01-01  2018-08-01
```